# how to retrieve the id from link URL to div using $_GET

Tags: php, get

on the same page I have

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `joedoe` ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $id = 'id';


<?php  echo "<a href=\'page.php?id=$rows[$id]\'>View</a>" ?>

<?php  echo " <div id=\'productId\' >$_GET[id]</div>" ?>
```

please tell me, how to retrieve the  id from link to div using $_GET

Comment: use `$_GET['id']`; instead of `$_GET[id'];`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju: same comment as before: That's just plain wrong: If you use an array in a double-quote delimited string, you _don't_ quote the keys, unless you're using curly brackets: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Basics: `echo "some $foo[bar] value";` is -technically- correct, though it's ambiguous. Better: `echo "some {$foo['bar']} value";`. Even better: `echo "some " . $foo['bar'] . ' value';` and better still: `printf("some %s value", $foo['bar']);`

Comment: This script php is inside the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes inside your array selector, around `id` index... 
`$_GET['id']`

Comment: That's just plain wrong: If you use an array in a double-quote delimited string, you _don't_ quote the keys, unless you're using curly brackets: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Basics: `echo "some $foo[bar] value";` is -technically- correct, though it's ambiguous. Better: `echo "some {$foo['bar']} value";`. Even better: `echo "some " . $foo['bar'] . ' value';` and better still: `printf("some %s value", $foo['bar']);`

Comment: Ah ok.  I never nest an array like that(Always concatenate when I need an array index).  Didn't know you could do it like shown above.

Comment: It's not my favourite PHP _"feature"_ either, but the fact is that quoted array keys don't work without the curly brackets. writing `echo "foo $foo['bar'] value";` won't even work as expected...